# Card Layout and toggle button problems

Tags: java, togglebutton, cardlayout

I have a problem when i use Card Layout and toggle buttons.
I want to change the background button when pressed for example:

```
private void togglebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    if(togglebtn.isSelected()){
       togglebtn.setBackground(Color.green);}
    else{
       togglebtn.setBackground(Color.red);}
}
```

And by putting this togglebtn on a normal JFrame it works. If i use a Panel with CardLayout and put this togglebtn on this panel with CardLayout it doesn't work.

```
private void cbItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt){ //cb is the combobox i use to switch the two panels
    CardLayout  cl = (CardLayout) (displaypane.getLayout()); //displaypane is the panel in which i used the CardLayout
    if (cb.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
        cl.show(displaypane, "card1"); //card1 is the first panel in displaypane
    } else {
        cl.show(displaypane, "card2"); //card2 is the second panel in displaypane
    }
}
```

Now if i use the same code i used before it doesn't work:

```
private void togglebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){ //the toggle button is in card1
    if(togglebtn.isSelected()){
       togglebtn.setBackground(Color.green);}
    else{
       togglebtn.setBackground(Color.red);}
}
```

It only shows the red background but not the green one, so the togglebutton can't be selected. What's the difference of having a CardLayout?

Comment: Please provide an ssccee http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain the problem you have with `CardLayout` here. In fact I could not get it work with simple `JFrame` either.
But if you want to change background colors of a button you need to initialize it with:

```
togglebtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
togglebtn.setOpaque(true);
```

Make it opaque and removing the fill of content area ensures that your ui look & feel wont over paint your defined background colors.

Comment: If i try to change the color of the toggle button in a JFrame without CardLayout, the togglebutton, when pressed,  changes its background because it is selected.

Comment: But if i try to change  the color of the toggle button in a JFrame with CardLayout, the togglebutton, when pressed,doesn't  change its background because it isn't selected. Why?

Comment: I think we need more code from you since this should work. I used [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java) sample code for `CardLayout`  and added a `JToggleButton` with my mentioned methods and your `ActionPerformed` method and it behaved as expected.

Comment: This is all the program, except the main code. I use Netbeans, so the program is pretty much reduced, but it's the same of yours.

Comment: The "main code" seems quite important here. Please add it.

Comment: Once i created the project in Netbeans i didn't even change "main".